# Is it possible to pre-commit run on --from-ref/--to-ref and staged files together

Tags: git, pre-commit.com

When I invoke:

- `pre-commit run --from-ref origin/develop --to-ref HEAD`: it runs on already committed files
- `pre-commit run`: it runs on staged files

Is there a way to have `pre-commit` run on both in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would ever want to do that -- seems like an XY problem

that said, it's always possible to utilize `pre-commit run --files` to run on whatever set of files you want to

combining the two:

```bash
(git diff --staged --name-only -z && git diff --name-only -z origin/develop...HEAD) | xargs -0 pre-commit run --files
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: My motivation is having parity between local dev and CI.  In local dev I want to run on staged files, in CI I want it to run on commits above `develop`.  I want to have the same command for both, and ideally it's a one-liner.  What you suggested will work, so thank you!

Comment: that doesn't seem like a good idea -- you're going to make local slower for no reason